# How to find the first and second highest series of numbers in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, pattern-matching, series

I have array of number and I want to find the highest series of numbers from array.

I have tried getting the consecutive series from an array But that's not the solution I'm looking for.

`[3766, 3987, 4046, 4187, 4489, 3700, 3307, 3336, 4113, 4286, 1278, 5676, 3140, 3299, 2617, 4928, 4498]`

This is my array and I want to find the highest series when `sum()`
and highest by length as well and maximum series length is 3.
 So actually I am expecting these results.
 `4046, 4187, 4489`

Please ask if you didn't understand the problem.
First highest series 
`4046, 4187, 4489` 
and second highest is
`4928, 4498`

Comment: What is the length of each series? If there is no limit, the series can just be the whole array.

Comment: What defines a series? Wouldn't `3766, 3987, 4046, 4187, 4489` be a series too?

Comment: What would be the desired solution for [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17], and when you answer, why not add one more value to it?

Comment: Also `when sum() and highest by length as well` - you can't maximize for two values at the same time. You want two separate calculations?

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned. maximum series length limit is 3. @KeroppiMomo

Comment: So second highest means length not equal to the length of the longest? How does highest length play into all of this?

Comment: Highest is 3 and minimum is 2 there can be by series we are looking for increasing numbers or decreasing numbers list.
Length is what helps us assume it's a series.

Comment: So, you want the sequences from length 3 to 2 ordered by their sum?

Comment: Are you looking for a sequence of numbers increasing / decreasing in order with length of min 2 and max 3 with highest sum?

Comment: yes exactly @FordAnderson

Comment: Yes exactly @briosheje

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know if this helps.. I am sure it could be optimized.

```
var arr = [3766, 3987, 4046, 4187, 4489, 3700, 3307, 3336, 4113, 4286, 1278, 5676, 3140, 3299, 2617, 4928, 4498];
var maxLength = 3; //Maximum length of series
var curLength = 0; //Keeping track of current length

var series = []; //Series that makes maximum sum
var tmpSeries = []; 
var currentMax = 0; //Current maximum value.

findSeries();

function findSeries()
{
    var tmpMax = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        var isInc = curIncStat = (arr[i] > arr[i +1]) ? "I" : "D";

        /*Iterate till one of the condition fails.
        1. maxLength is reached
        2. sequence changes from Inc to Dec
        3. Run out of array
        */

        while(true)
        {
            //Checking for fail conditions
            if(curIncStat != isInc || curLength == maxLength || (i + 1) > arr.length)
            {
                //Checking if tmpSeries sum is greater than currentMax
                if(tmpMax >  currentMax)
                {
                    series = [];
                    series.push(tmpSeries);
                    currentMax = tmpMax;

                }

                //Resetting all values.
                tmpMax = 0;
                tmpSeries = [];
                curLength = 0;
                break;
            }

            tmpSeries.push(arr[i + curLength]);
            tmpMax += arr[i + curLength];

            curIncStat = (arr[i + curLength] > arr[i + curLength + 1]) ? "I" : "D";
            curLength++;
        }
    }
    console.log(arr)
    console.log(series);
    console.log(currentMax);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution relying on function generators, the below method generates all the needed sequences of X elements (in your case, 2 to 3).
The method takes an array as argument, a minimum size and a maximum size, yielding each sequence it encounters for each size (so, it starts with [3766, 3987], then [3987, 4046] and so on).

Next, I've implemented another little method that returns the element with the highest sum in an array of arrays of integers, starting from the desired size. This can surely be accomplished in a better way, but I though that iterating the original array in a single shot would make things easier to manage.

```js
const input = [3766, 3987, 4046, 4187, 4489, 3700, 3307, 3336, 4113, 4286, 1278, 5676, 3140, 3299, 2617, 4928, 4498];

/*
  Builds all the sequences from left to right of an array, of all the sizes between minSize and maxSize included.
*/
function* buildSequences(arr, minSize, maxSize) {
  for (let i = minSize; i <= maxSize; i++) {
    let counter = 0;
    do {
      yield arr.slice(counter, counter + i);
      counter++;
    }
    while (counter <= arr.length - i);
  }
}

// Acquire the highest element in an array of arrays, by returning the element with the highest sum and specified size (length).
const getHighestBySerieSize = (arr, size) => {
  let sumArray = (a) => a.reduce((a,b) => a + b);
  return arr.filter(i => i.length === size).sort((a,b) => sumArray(a) < sumArray(b))[0];
}

// Build all sequences of 2 to 3 elements, fromm left to right.
const sequences = [...buildSequences(input, 2, 3)];

// Find the highest of each.
const [highestThreeSerie, highestTwoSerie] = [getHighestBySerieSize(sequences, 2), getHighestBySerieSize(sequences, 3)];

console.log(highestThreeSerie, highestTwoSerie);
```

Comment: Wow.. I love your code. I will get there one day :) But I am not sure its giving the required resume.. Or maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Well it's giving what he asked, I've double-checked the results and the sorting is actually correct :P. Anyway, if the expected result is different, it's enough to edit the sorting and whatever, I'm not sure whether he wants just the maximum ones or all the pairs. If the pair is the desired result, it's actually very easy.

Comment: Like I said I could be wrong :) Hey.. Seriously! Love your code!

Comment: @FordAnderson thanks, I personally prefere the generator approach other than others when generations are required... I feel it makes the code slightly easier to read :)

Comment: Exactly.. Would you suggest a book or a site for learning JS mate? Learnt a few things from your code today.. thanks!

Comment: @FordAnderson I personally didn't follow any book, I just happen to work in javascript and be an active member of this community. If you want to learn something here, I recommend you to take a look at these users: NinaScholz, CertainPerformance, Bergi, Quentin, Adeneo, Adiga, VLAZ and some other that I don't remember now. Starting from these and looking at their answers is one of the best ways to discover new approaches, if you happen to understand some of Nina's answer you definitely can say that you learnt something :P.

Comment: Thanks @briosheje That's great but doesn't solve my problem the third answer below is perfect for me. Thanks.

Comment: @ShababQaisar no problems, hope you learnt something from the answer anyway ;)